# transfer files over ftp that are on different directories

Tags: ftp, cmd

lets say I am working on index.php and configuring style.css that is on css folder. can I transfer both files using comand line to the server using one line?

Comment: I serched the net net and found comand mput, but I could not find any tutorial on trasfering a set of files this is for convenience lets say I am working on a set of files when I save them all I want to be able to ftp them in one bach I am usin dream weather as an editor but there is so such function and everything is very slow I was thinking of command line approach

Comment: windows 7 I am conecting to godady.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload a files by creating an ftp command script file (e.g. ftp.txt) with the content:

```
(username)
(password)
cd /folder-on-server
binary
put c:\myfolder\myfile.jpg
put c:\myfolder\style.css
```

Then on the command line

```
ftp -s:ftp.txt ftp.example.com
```

Based on: http://wiki.tekkies.co.uk/General_Technical#FTP_using_xp_cmdshell_-_sql2k